# How can I add a line break or html inside of a Panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, function, foreach

I am trying to create a menu with the following code.  But I cannot figure out how to get each LinkButton to appear on seperate lines.

```
MenuPanel.Controls.Clear();
foreach (FormList f in forms)
{
  if (f.IsActive == "y")
  {
     FormUserControl fc = (FormUserControl)LoadControl(f.StartControl);
     LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
     lb.Text = fc.Title;
     MenuPanel.Controls.Add(lb);
     // I want some sort of line break here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`LiteralControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx) class to insert a line break...

```
MenuPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
```

Or use CSS to make your links block-level elements...

```
#menu a { display: block; }
```

Comment: I had to use a LiteralControl, but essentially this worked great.

Comment: Good answer, usually I create numerous of Literal with the text of <br /> because it can't be reused. Your suggestion clean up my code a little.

Answer (score 3):

FYI : If you have already added **the panel control** in the aspx(design-view) and if you want to use the above accepted answer in .cs file (code-behind)., then you will be running into type errors. So in that case, you could use this way. Please note the **small cased** "new".

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer has already been accepted but I'd like to suggest a different option. If you want a vertical list of elements then it might be worth using a ul or ol element. This means you don't have to use the dreaded br tag or any hacks to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
div.Text = "&nbsp;";
MenuPanel.Controls.Add(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

in the panel control u can use lable control which have " value in text property

```
Label lb1 = new Label();
lb1.Text = "<br>";

Panel1.Controls.Add(lb1);
```